# Perl web hosting for script with crontab

Tags: perl, hosting, web-hosting

I am looking for some kind of web hosting where I can store my Perl script and run in using for instance crontab. I found out Google App Engine, but ... it is not what i would like to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge you need either a web hosting service supporting CGI which you could hit regularly to get your script executed (using a [Yahoo Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) for instance) or a full ssh access.